# What is the netCore SSE2 counterpart of _mm_set1_epi32

Tags: c#, .net-core, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm porting some c++ SIMD instruction code to netCore Intrinsics and went over following line:

```
__m128i ssd = _mm_set1_epi32((unsigned __int32)(alpha_value & 0x000000FF) << 24); //ALPHA CHANNEL MASK
```

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse2?view=netcore-3.1) of netCore SSE2 Intrinsics I could not find any corresponding method for the _mm_set1_epi32 intrinsic.

What this instruction does is setting each of the 4 32 bit uint in the 128 bit vector to a specified value.

How to do that in netCore with `Vector128<uint>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in that class, instead `Vector128` has static a [`Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128.create?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector128_Create_System_UInt32_) function with various overloads that can be used in place of both the `set1`-group and `set`-group of functions. Since they are overloads and don't have the type in the name, special care must be taken that the parameter type is correct.